# Is there anywhere in Nong Khai that can exchange Lao Kip to Thai Baht?

Tags: thailand, exchange

Normally it's best to change money in the smaller / less developed country.

But on my way across the border from Vientiane, Laos to Nong Khai, Thailand two days ago I didn't know how much kip I should keep for the bus over the bridge, and once I did the bus was about to leave so I jumped aboard.

The next morning I headed to the Asawann Shopping Complex where I knew there was a Krungsri Bank exchange booth. But they don't deal in Lao Kip, despite what comments found by Googling say.

I recently spent a month in Nong Khai and didn't spot any other money changer. But the lady at Krungsri seemed to be trying to give me directions to another exchange though my Thai skills were not enough to understand. I wandered all around the shopping centre and couldn't find another change place.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are at least two.

There is [an exchange called **"Chang Tai"**](https://www.facebook.com/p/%E0%B8%8A%E0%B9%89%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%87%E0%B9%84%E0%B8%97-%E0%B9%80%E0%B8%AD%E0%B9%87%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%8B%E0%B9%8C%E0%B9%80%E0%B8%8A%E0%B8%99%E0%B8%88%E0%B9%8C-%E0%B8%AB%E0%B8%99%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%87%E0%B8%84%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%A2-Chang-Tai-Exchange-Nong-Khai-100063644374315/), located inside the west part of the **Asawann Shopping Complex**, near the **Lotus's supermarket**. (There is also an east part of the Asawann Complex just over the big road that has a Big C supermarket and I didn't spot an exchange there.)

They're open from 10.00am to 7.00pm seven days a week.

Note that I did not actually ask them if they would buy or sell Kip, I just trusted their display.

[image: The signage of the Chang Tai Exchange]

The exchange rate display showing LAK near the bottom showing `0.0013` buying vs `0.0018` selling rates. The official rate today is `0.0017` for comparison. I don't know if this is particularly good or bad compared to other exchanges in Thailand. (I might be able to check how it compares to rates in Laos later and add to this answer.)
[image: The exchange rate display screen]

The other one I found is right by the gate to the Friendship Bridge, two doors to the right of the 7-Eleven and it's called ["Twelve Victory Exchange"](https://maps.app.goo.gl/BkBE1KVaPVYnQhWz8).
[image: near the 7-Eleven at the border crossing]
They don't have a sign with the rates but I asked them if they sell Lao Kip. They said yes and the rate is ฿1 Baht gets you ₭550 Kip. The reviews on Google Maps says their rates are bad. I changed my kip and baht at the bank near Immigration on the Lao side again but I noted that their rate is ₭637 for ฿1. The rule that the deal is always better in the smaller/poorer country holds true.